# How to use Android media recorder to get max amplitude?

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

I've seen various posts addressing issues with the method [getMaxAmplitude()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#getMaxAmplitude()) from [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder) but I still haven't been able to resolve my problem. I want to constantly update a TextView with the amplitude of sound in decibels. I tried achieving this by running a handler every 1 second with a function that calls this method, but it seems that the MediaRecorder object is always null even after I initialize it(which I find odd). BTW, I have added all the necessary permissions for audio recording in android. What do I need to change in my code to be able to access the getMaxAmplitude() method?

```
package com.inversepalindrome.sensorbox;

import com.cardiomood.android.controls.gauge.SpeedometerGauge;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;


public class SoundActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;

    private SpeedometerGauge speedometer;

    private TextView soundAmplitudeText;

    private final int AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    private final int AUDIO_RECORDING_DELAY = 1000;
    private final double referenceAmplitude = 0.0001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                    android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        speedometer = findViewById(R.id.speedometer);

        speedometer.setLabelConverter(new SpeedometerGauge.LabelConverter() {
            @Override
            public String getLabelFor(double progress, double maxProgress) {
                return String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", progress);
            }
        });
        speedometer.setMaxSpeed(120);
        speedometer.setMajorTickStep(20);
        speedometer.setMinorTicks(1);
        speedometer.setLabelTextSize(32);
        speedometer.addColoredRange(0, 40, Color.GREEN);
        speedometer.addColoredRange(40, 80, Color.YELLOW);
        speedometer.addColoredRange(80, 120, Color.RED);

        soundAmplitudeText = findViewById(R.id.soundAmplitudeValueText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        startRecording();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();

        stopRecording();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (requestCode == AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE) {
                startRecording();

                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final double amplitude = getAmplitude();

                        speedometer.setSpeed(amplitude);
                        soundAmplitudeText.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f", amplitude));

                        handler.postDelayed(this, AUDIO_RECORDING_DELAY);
                    }
                }, AUDIO_RECORDING_DELAY);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No audio recording permissions given!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startRecording(){
        if(mediaRecorder != null)
        {
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");

            try {
                mediaRecorder.prepare();
                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording(){
        if(mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            mediaRecorder.release();
            mediaRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    private double getAmplitude(){
        if(mediaRecorder != null){
            final double maxAmplitude = mediaRecorder.getMaxAmplitude();
            final double amplitude = 20 * Math.log10(maxAmplitude / referenceAmplitude);

            return amplitude;
        }
        else{
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: After fixing some issues that were pointed out my app is crashing on the 
getMaxAmplitudeCall with the following debug message:

```
1501-6480/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2019-01-18 15:23:54.983 2362-10949/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2019-01-18 15:23:54.987 2362-10949/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2019-01-18 15:23:54.987 2362-10949/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
```

Comment: 1: Why do you start recording onResume and stoping on Pause. Those methods are for the lifecycle of your activity.  Have you read this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle ?

Comment: I think that I have to stop recording if the user leaves the application, however I am not sure if I should do this.

Comment: Yes you must!. but you must not start recording onResume. The user explicitly have to command to start recording with a button or something.

Comment: 2. You have to ask for recording permission after the user click your button. Remember permissions can be changed any time from outside your app.

Comment: I am trying to get real time data of the amplitude of the audio with the media recorder, so I want to constantly poll this method. The user is being asked the permission as soon as he enters the activity.

Comment: The MediaRecorder is a state machine read the documentation and make sure you understand how those states works, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#getMaxAmplitude()   getMaxAmplitude
added in API level 1
public int getMaxAmplitude ()
Returns the maximum absolute amplitude that was sampled since the last call to this method. Call this only after the setAudioSource().

Comment: your problem is onPause. Read my answer. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in my comments, but your problem is you are calling in onPause stop recording, stoping and releasing your MediaRecorder. It might happen when you don't have permission for recording. When the dialog asking for permission appears, stopRecording is being called and thus your audio recorder is null and released.

If you had permissions already this will not happen. Give it a try.

Also, In startRecording method check if your media recorder is null. You have if is it different of null.

Comment: I removed the call on the pause method to check if this was the issue but now my app is crashing whenever I call  getMaxAmplitude.

Comment: You were right I added a button mechanism for record/stop and it stopped crashing.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(mediaRecorder != null)
    {
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
```

YOu have the check backwards.  So it never initializes

Comment: You're right I missed that and I fixed it, but now my application is crashing whenever I call getMaxAmplitude.